# What does "Run command as a login shell" do?

Tags: command-line

I have a few separate programs installed, some of which require me to go into my GUI terminal settings and enable/disable the "Run command as a login shell" option to get either working.

Example:

I installed [Ruby on Rails](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm). Unfortunately I have to go into the terminal options and enable "Run command as login shell" for it to be in my PATH.

This wasn't too much of an issue up until I installed [sexy-bash-prompt](https://github.com/twolfson/sexy-bash-prompt), which works only if the option is disabled.

So my question is essentially: what does "Run command as login shell" do? Is there a way to get the things that run when it's disabled to run when you do run as login shell?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Assuming that your shell is Bash (the default in Ubuntu), these are the differences:

- When running as a **login** shell, Bash will read `~/.bash_profile` (or, if that doesn't exist, `~/.profile`) on startup. In some cases, this file reads `~/.bashrc` as well.
- When running as a **non-login** shell, Bash will read `~/.bashrc`.

So, why do you see different behaviors when running as a login/non-login shell? Because your `.bash_profile`/`.profile` is doing different things than your `.bashrc`.

The solution I would recommend in your case is to **copy** the customizations made to `.bash_profile`/`.profile`, **paste** them into `.bashrc` and **disable** "Run command as a login shell".

Comment: Ahh ok.  I figured it had to do with what login profile it read (source'ing .bashrc fixes some of the issues I had).  I'll give that a go, sorry for the horribly written question.

Comment: Thanks for the concise explanation. It is not uncommon to see people just keep their customizations in .bashrc and have .bash_profile to source .bashrc.  Login specific customizations should be kept in .bash_profile only.

Comment: Why not just source .bashrc into .bash_profile and leave the login shell on? Is that feasible?