# command line not working

Tags: 13.04, command-line, dash-shell

after I initially installed ubuntu , I can run 'll' in my terminal.

But after I checked a "Run command as login shell" in terminal preferences I cannot run "ll" command any more in terminal.

Something I am missing?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Normaly, `ll` is not a shell command. It is just an alias defined in `~/.bashrc` file as follow:

```
alias ll='ls -alF'
```

So, check in your `~/.bashrc` file if you have anymore the above line (in my `.bashrc` file is located somewhere at the line 93).

Comment: IT is there , How come  after I checked  "Run command as login shell" in terminal preferences it is lost?

Comment: @icn can you post on http://paste.ubuntu.com/ your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_aliases` files?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333446/what-does-run-command-as-a-login-shell-do).

Running command as login shell executes ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile, instead of ~/.bashrc. If you still want 'll' to work when using login shell, put

```
alias ll='ls -alF'
```

in either ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile.