# Run command as a login shell in pantheon terminal

Tags: pantheon, elementary-theme

where I can find option: “Run command as a login shell”  in pantheon terminal ?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-terminal/+bug/909717 it seems that is not implemented...

Answer (score 2):

You can run pantheon terminal this command:

```
pantheon-terminal . ~/.bashrc
```

When I run pantheon-terminal without `. ~/.bashrc` rvm for ruby not work, but with this option all work fine. I setting this command on hot corner - very comfortably.

You can read information about bash on this case - its help me run pantheon-terminal correctly: [What does “Run command as a login shell” do?](https://askubuntu.com/a/337477/234449)

Answer (score 1):

I installed gnome-terminal and solved this problem.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to change the Shell Pantheon Terminal uses, also. To enable me to use the Shell enhancements provided by the Trezor Agent (trezor_agent).

I found it can be updated in dconf, using the following command:

```
$ gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings shell '/bin/bash'
```

It however, doesn't seem to 'like' (it just hangs) command flags etc (e.g. `--login`). So an alternative is to compose your own script and use this as your Shell:

*(for bash)*

```
#!/bin/sh
exec bash --login
```

*(for zsh)*

```
#!/bin/zsh
exec zsh --login
```

Save this file (I opted for `/bin/tsh`, but the name is unimportant), make it executable:

```
$ sudo chmod +x /bin/tsh
```

Then update Pantheon to use it as your Shell:

```
$ gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings shell '/bin/tsh'
```